# Error 404 static files in django 2.0

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates

I'm trying to locate all my static files in django 2.0. But when i run the server only i got 404 errors

this is my settings code

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/var/www/example.com/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)
```

and my url code

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('naturalUser.urls'))
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

404 errors

```
[11/Feb/2018 00:45:11] "GET /static/bower_components/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1869
[11/Feb/2018 00:45:11] "GET /static/internal/css/general.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1797
[11/Feb/2018 00:45:11] "GET /static/internal/css/AdminLTE.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1812
[11/Feb/2018 00:45:11] "GET /static/internal/css/skins/all-skins.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1833
[11/Feb/2018 00:45:11] "GET /static/internal/js/adminlte.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1806
[11/Feb/2018 00:45:11] "GET /static/bower_components/jquery/internal/jquery.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1863
[11/Feb/2018 00:45:11] "GET /static/bower_components/bootstrap/internal/js/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1890
[11/Feb/2018 00:45:11] "GET /static/bower_components/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1869
[11/Feb/2018 00:45:11] "GET /static/internal/css/AdminLTE.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1812
[11/Feb/2018 00:45:11] "GET /static/internal/css/general.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1797
[11/Feb/2018 00:45:11] "GET /static/internal/css/skins/all-skins.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1833
[11/Feb/2018 00:45:11] "GET /static/bower_components/jquery/internal/jquery.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1863
[11/Feb/2018 00:45:11] "GET /static/bower_components/bootstrap/internal/js/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1890
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```